# Wifi Hotspots not visible

Tags: networking, internet, 19.04

I was having a bit of trouble connecting to the internet through my phone but the wifi router worked fine. 
After following the instructions to fix the issue (http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/05/install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-linuxmint.html), and restarting my laptop, none of the Hotspots appeared.

Comment: Could you please specify, why did you install the drives in your Laptop when you were having internet issues on your phone.

Comment: I could connect to the internet on my phone but couldn't connect my laptop to the internet via the mobile Hotspot. My friend suggested that it might be a driver issue

Comment: It's alright now .I fixed it. I tinkered with `echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` with  a bit and now its fine.

Comment: Its good to hear that your issue is resolved. You can close the query then :)